# Use multiple server blocks in NGINX on same host and same port

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy, http, nextcloud

I want to configure the server such that the root of the server serves some static files, which a specific endpoing, /nextcloud serves nextcloud on the same domain.

Here is my nginx.conf -

```
worker_processes  8;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80 http2;
        listen [::]:80 http2;
        server_name  localhost;
        root   /srv/http/;
        location / {
            index  index.html index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            autoindex on;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nextcloud.conf

```
upstream php-handler {
    server unix:/run/nextcloud/nextcloud.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name nextcloud;

    root /usr/share/webapps/;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known {
        location = /.well-known/carddav { return 301 /nextcloud/remote.php/dav/; }
        location = /.well-known/caldav  { return 301 /nextcloud/remote.php/dav/; }

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge    { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }
        location /.well-known/pki-validation    { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }

        return 301 /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri;
    }

    location ^~ /nextcloud {
        client_max_body_size 512M;
        client_body_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
        gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/wasm application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

        add_header Referrer-Policy                      "no-referrer"   always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options               "nosniff"       always;
        add_header X-Download-Options                   "noopen"        always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options                      "SAMEORIGIN"    always;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies    "none"          always;
        add_header X-Robots-Tag                         "none"          always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection                     "1; mode=block" always;

        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

        index index.php index.html /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri;

        location = /nextcloud {
            if ( $http_user_agent ~ ^DavClnt ) {
                return 302 /nextcloud/remote.php/webdav/$is_args$args;
            }
        }

        location ~ ^/nextcloud/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)(?:$|/)    { return 404; }
        location ~ ^/nextcloud/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console)                  { return 404; }

        location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
            rewrite ^/nextcloud/(?!index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+|.+\/richdocumentscode\/proxy) /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;

            try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;         # Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;     # Enable pretty urls
            fastcgi_pass php-handler;

            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;

            fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:css|js|svg|gif|png|jpg|ico|wasm|tflite)$ {
            try_files $uri /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri;
            expires 6M;         # Cache-Control policy borrowed from `.htaccess`
            access_log off;     # Optional: Don't log access to assets

            location ~ \.wasm$ {
                default_type application/wasm;
            }
        }

        location ~ \.woff2?$ {
            try_files $uri /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri;
            expires 7d;         # Cache-Control policy borrowed from `.htaccess`
            access_log off;     # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        }

        location /nextcloud/remote {
            return 301 /nextcloud/remote.php$request_uri;
        }

        location /nextcloud {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this configuration doesn't work. With this config, I get a 404 when I try accessing /nextcloud/.

If I disable the static files server block in nginx.conf, I can access /nextcloud/ but then, I can't access my static files. How do I configure such that both work, on the same host and same port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure both in same `server` block.

When nginx receives a request, it selects the virtual host to use based on the HTTP `Host` header in the request and port number.

Your current configuration would serve `nextcloud` if you accessed the service using `http://nextcloud/nextcloud`, provided that you have DNS configured properly for `nextcloud` name.

What you likely want is something like this in your nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes  8;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80 http2;
        listen [::]:80 http2;
        server_name  localhost;
        root   /srv/http/;
        location / {
            index  index.html index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            autoindex on;
        }
        
        location /nextcloud {
            ...
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And removing the other configuration.

Comment: No. I've run upwards of 100 virtual hosts on the same nginx instance. Each in its own server block. If the question were how to retrieve files via http://localhost/nextcloud then the config here would resolve the issue. That was not what was askied. Further the organisation of config files is undermined by putting server blocks in the same file as the http block. Don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use the same port in 1 virtual host, instead clone or create another virtual host / config and use the same port with different server_name or domain. Please use [this blog](https://bobcares.com/blog/multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-nginx/) as reference